# Access denied error during initialization of a sandboxed process

Tags: chromium, sandbox, windows-server, appcontainer

I am tying to launch a process in Chromium sandbox with App Container enabled, I didn't change any settings, so it's just a normal startup and it, actually, works well on my Windows 11 system, however on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, version 10.0.17763 I am getting access denied error (the application was unable to start correctly: `0xc0000022`) during startup of the child (target) process. I can't debug this process because it fails before main function somewhere during loading dependencies process. Here are some screenshots with more details. [image: ProcMon target process actions][image: ProcMon failed action]

I asked ChatGPT 4 to help, but it gave very generic response like update your system, disable antivirus, check container permissions, execute `icacls`, which is not installed on the Datacenter machine.

The most interesting part is `base.dll` and some other libraries are successfully read and subsequently passed to `QueryFileMapping, QueryNameInformationFile and QuerySecurityFile` actions, however the same workflow with `libc++.dll` located in the same build directory is different.

This happens only if application container is applied (by  calling `config->AddAppContainerProfile(package_name, true)` which detects that container with such a name has been found and "opens" it, gets sid, initializes container base classes in broker process.

I also tried to launch the target process without broker (without alternate dektop, lower token) by a special AppContainer launcher app and it worked good.

Also I can see the following warnings in the output:

```
> ReturnHr(2) tid(2534) 800700B7 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
> onecore\base\appmodel\identity\lib\packageidentity.cpp(85)\kernelbase.dll!773561DB: (caller: 612C9D3A) ReturnHr(3) tid(2534) 800700B7 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
> Msg:[Moniker test_env DispName Chrome Sandbox] 
> onecore\ds\security\gina\profile\profext\appcontainer.cpp(1808)\profext.dll!612C9D55: (caller: 612CA83F) LogHr(1) tid(2534) 800700B7 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
> Msg:[Name test_env display Chrome Sandbox] 
>
```

but I believe those are just telling that app container already exists.
Please help to resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to run `chrome.exe --enable-logging --v=1`, it will show useful information about unable to run a child process.

Comment: @273K,  I don't use chrome.exe, I have my own broker and child processes, my broker at some point does a call to BrokerServices->SpawnTarget, but it returns no errors and result is SBOX_ALL_OK, the process is started but it's frozen, I write some JSONs to stdin of a child and unfroze with Resume method. All these work fine on my Windows 11, but fails on DataCenter machine

Comment: @273K, I checked if a fresh version of Google Chrome browser is running on this machine and it works fine